RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified. (Android 14) flutter_in_purches
I want to add support for Android 14 to my Flutter project, but I encountered an issue. The issue is with the flutter_inapp_purchase package. When I initialize it, I get this error.
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts.

E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3071)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3055)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3038)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2980)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6380)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1876)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1811)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1799)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:755)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
com.android.billingclient.api.zzo.zzc(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.1.0:1)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
com.android.billingclient.api.zzp.zze(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.1.0:3)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.startConnection(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.1.0:36)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
com.dooboolab.flutterinapppurchase.AndroidInappPurchasePlugin.onMethodCall(AndroidInappPurchasePlugin.kt:84)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown
Source:12) E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:1013)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:328)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9210)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:586)
E/MethodChannel#flutter_inapp(20036): at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
I/flutter (20036): Error initializing platform state:
PlatformException(error, com.icebreakrr.classic: One of
RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a
receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts,
null, java.lang.SecurityException: com.icebreakrr.classic: One of
RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a
receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
I/flutter (20036): at
android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3071) I/flutter
(20036): at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3055)
I/flutter (20036): at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3038) I/flutter (20036):
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2980) I/flutter
(20036): at
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:6380)
I/flutter (20036): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1876)
I/flutter (20036): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1811)
I/flutter (20036): at
android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1799)
I/flutter (20036): at
android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:755)
I/flutter (20036): at
com.android.billingclient.api.zzo.zzc(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.1.0:1)
I/flutter (20036): at
com.android.billingclient.api.zzp.zze(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.1.0:3)
I/flutter (20036): at
com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl.startConnection(com.android.billingclient:billing@@5.1.0:36)
I/flutter (20036): at
com.dooboolab.flutterinapppurchase.AndroidInappPurchasePlugin.onMethodCall(AndroidInappPurchasePlugin.kt:84)
I/flutter (20036): at
io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
I/flutter (20036): at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
I/flutter (20036): at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
I/flutter (20036): at
io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown
Source:12) I/flutter (20036): at
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:1013) I/flutter
(20036): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
I/flutter (20036): at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
I/flutter (20036): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:328)
I/flutter (20036): at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9210) I/flutter
(20036): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) I/flutter
(20036): at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:586)
I/flutter (20036): at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
I/flutter (20036): )

Please help me to solve this issue.
I have tried to find a version of flutter_inapp_purchase that supports Android 14, but I haven't been able to find one.

You need to add receiver in AndroidManifest.xml file like this,
 <receiver
        android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY"
                android:permission = "com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

File Reference from official example :  https://github.com/dooboolab-community/flutter_inapp_purchase/blob/main/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
